# Using JGR with Apple OS after Mavericks 10.9.5

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

I tried to launch JGR 1.7-16 with Yosemite and then with El Capitan.All package dependencies were updated with R. Both R and RStudio load without problem.
JGR crashes immediately.
No guidance is offered from the [JGR website](http://www.rforge.net/JGR/) that has no activity since 2013.
Anybody know of a workaround?

Comment: Make sure you have everything up-to-date, have all the package dependencies met and have read all the package help pages.

Comment: I already updated everything directly with R

Comment: I seem to remember that the rosuda-stats mailing list is the one recommended for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the Google deducer group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/deducer/tjV1gsGSoVk): start up JGR + Deducer from R console via JGR()